How to play iphone notifications over Sonos speaker, when phone is charging
I have a phone charging station in my home that is separated from where my family spends most of their time. I'm interested in setting up an automation where: when an iPhone 8 is charging in the house using an inductive charger, it plays audio sound effects from iOS notifications (particularly text messages / imessages) over a Sonos One speaker (or a bluetooth speaker, as a backup) so that folks can hear them in another spot in the house. How might I enable this? What third-party services might I look into? The solution could also involve some custom programming.

I realize this is a thing some people use smart watches for, but we don't have and don't plan on getting those.

Definitely not as clean as what you're looking for, but one potential solution would be to use a wired dock with a headphone out port and plug that into the line-in on your speaker.
